# Sitecore Commerce Compatibility

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Is **Sitecore 9.1.0** (rev. 001564) compatible with Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.1 Initial Release ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on the [Sitecore Experience Commerce compatibility page](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/804595), it is not.

See below for table outlining the compatibility taken from there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. None of the Sitecore Experience Commerce versions is compatible with Sitecore 9.1.0.

See `Sitecore Experience Commerce` compatibility with `Sitecore XP And Modules` table here:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/804595